# Is it a way to get rid of Return button in iOS keyboard?

Tags: ios, uitextfield

I have custom workflow, so I do not need `Return` button. Is it a way to get rid of it?

I need a `Next` `Done` `Clear` auxiliary buttons, and because I use on keyboard panel also for date picker, I have the only option to place it at `inputAccessoryView`.

But then I do not need the standard `Done` or `Next` button.

Comment: I had a solution for this

Comment: I had posted check now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of trying to use any hacks maybe you should think about your workflow. Is it really so cool and intuitive that you want to force users to not use established patterns? When the user is done typing, does the user need to do other actions (press any buttons on the screen) or can some action be started? Also remember that the return key is still sent by Bluetooth keyboards.

If there's any other text field, the return button should be "Next". If not, then most likely "Done" is the button to use. It should then either trigger the action that your view is about or simply hide the keyboard.

Comment: I fine-tuned my question put into context, curious your opinion

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the part with date picker, I assume you'd like to add an accessory view to the date picker as well. I'd do it like this: use the standard "Done" button on the keyboard and put "Next" and "Clear" in the accessory view. The reason is that "Done" is the strongest action while "Next" and "Clear" are more or less convenience. In the accessory view for the date picker, additionally add the "Done" button.

Comment: I like @DarkDust solution, the only small annoying thing is when jumping from `textfield` to `date picker`, the position of `Next` is **at different places on the screen** so need to move your finger to navigate.

Comment: With "different places", do you mean because of the height difference of the keyboard vs. date picker? I'd order the buttons in the accessory view "Clear" and "Next" for keyboard, and "Clear", "Next" and "Done" for the date picker. So the first two always have the same x-position.

Comment: "different places" I mean that `Next` is in `inputAccessoryView` so above keyboard for `date picker` but 'under' / part of keyboard for `text field`

Comment: Well, I was suggesting to use "Done" in the keyboard, not "Next". But it only slightly changes the problem that _one_ button will sometimes be in the accessory view and sometimes not. The alternative is to always show all three buttons, but then a button will be displayed twice. It's up to you to decide which one is worse :-)

Answer (score 0):

On the UITextView or UITextField, use the required type for the button

```
textView.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDone;
```

The whole list:

```
typedef enum : NSInteger  {
   UIReturnKeyDefault ,
   UIReturnKeyGo ,
   UIReturnKeyGoogle ,
   UIReturnKeyJoin ,
   UIReturnKeyNext ,
   UIReturnKeyRoute ,
   UIReturnKeySearch ,
   UIReturnKeySend ,
   UIReturnKeyYahoo ,
   UIReturnKeyDone ,
   UIReturnKeyEmergencyCall ,
} UIReturnKeyType;
```

As being mentioned on https://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextInputTraits_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/UIReturnKeyType

Comment: There is no such an option like let it empty?!

Comment: Indeed there is no way of hiding it or appear empty.